# Output a text that doesn't output any of the characters used in the instructions to output the text

Tags: string, code-challenge

**Main objective**

The main objective is to output a text, it doesn't mind which text or where the text gets its output (it can be on a browser window, the default console etc).

It just requires the condition that what is output must be indeed "real chars" (the ones in UNICODE for example), it's not considered valid to display graphics that simulate chars.

**Condition to program**

Now into the conditions to program:

None of the characters that appear in the code must appear in the output.

The created string cannot be infinite (continuosly being created in a loop without end)

**Test cases**

So let's say that you code  is

```
abcdef
```

If that displayed

```
ghijk
```

The code would be valid, but if this displayed:

```
chiij
```

Then it would not be valid

Obviously something like

print("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");

That displays

```
 aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

would be invalid.

**Challenge**

Write a code that displays a text as defined.

**Scoring**

In this [code-challenge](/questions/tagged/code-challenge), your answer is scored by the ratio between string length and number of bytes in code (string length / code length), where the highest score wins.

Good luck!

Comment: @StepHen How would this be a dupe of that?

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder anyone can just copy the top answers there and destroy any answer currently on here?

Comment: @StepHen Yeah, you're right. The first one has `> 100E` score here.

Comment: Fwiw I voted to close as too broad.

Comment: The empty program in Japt [prints `undefined`](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=&input=), would that give it a score of 9/0 = infinity?

Comment: Yes, @ETHproductions. I think you have won.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 0 bytes, score: 1/0 = ∞

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8DwQA)

That's right, the empty program in Jelly prints `0`.

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page), score: 1000.6

```
⁶³ȷ³x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9R47ZDm09sP7S54v9/AA)

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 2 bytes, score: 95 / 2 = 47.5

```
ØṖ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///wjIc7p/3/DwA)

This yields the set of all printable ASCII: `` !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~ `` and a space (95 bytes)

Comment: The same score, ∞ can be achieved in 0 bytes in Stuck, in which the empty program prints `Hello, World!`

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 1 byte, score: 26

```
G
```

[Try it online](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=G&debug=0)

This outputs: `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz` (26 bytes).

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 14 bytes, score 27672892.1429

```python
print"\n"*9**9
```

Prints 387420490 newlines. Output truncated on TIO.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v6AoM69EKSZPSctSS8vy/38A)

Comment: `print"\n"*19**19` would have a score of `1,236512285E23` :)

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder I could not find an interpreter where larger numbers would work. Slightly larger numbers throw either `MemoryError` or `IOError`. Your number gives `OverflowError: cannot fit 'long' into an index-sized integer`

Answer (score 0):

## cQuents, score: 1.8530202E33 / 9 bytes = 2.0589113E32

```
#9^8e9::n
```

Score is based on math, not runs of the program.

Prints `43046721000000000` copies of `43046721000000000` joined on `,`.

### Explanation

```
 #9^8e9      n = (9^8) * 10^9
       ::    Print the sequence from 1 to n
         n   Each item in the sequence equals n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4sTc0rKf7/X9k4zjjV0soq7/9/AA) (truncated)

Comment: The score is `3,87420489E17`

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder made it bigger, so the score's bigger

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 91 bytes, score = 67067/91 = 737

```python
s="s=forinage(35,127):chtp*0"
for f in range(35,127):
 if chr(f)not in s:print(chr(f)*1000)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v9hWqdg2Lb8oMy8xPVXD2FTH0Mhc0yo5o6RAy0CJCyihkKaQmadQlJiHJM2lkJmmkJxRpJGmmZdfApIvtioAGlGiARHUMjQwMND8/x8A)